# Поиск "дублей" в таблице MySQL в поле utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Имеем к примеру такой запрос.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `utsna_virtuemart_medias`
WHERE
    `file_url` = 'images\stories\virtuemart\category\Varivas.jpg'
```

Этот запрос не находит запись в базе, так как ее попросту нет в точном виде, а поле у нас определено как `utf8_general_ci`.

Вопрос, `LIKE` в данном случае по тем же правилам будет работать, то есть искать точное совпадение с учетом регистра?

Каким образом можно найти строку в базе, с учетом `utf8_general_ci` если она например имеет вид `'images\stories\virtuemart\category\VaRivaS.jpg'` ?

Comment: `_ci` - игнорировать регистр.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `utsna_virtuemart_medias`
WHERE
    LOWER(`file_url`) = LOWER('images\stories\virtuemart\category\Varivas.jpg')
```